How to use getLogger with custom logger class?
I'm trying to create a custom logger to be able to add custom params to info, error etc. methods. I use setDefaultClass, however, when I try to use getLogger in other modules it always returns Logger class instead of CustomLogger.
I figured it's possible to overwrite logger.class with CustomLogger, but this feels lile a red flag.
Is there a "good" way to use CustomLogger the same as Logger?

Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51938027/674039

I was hoping that there is better way than modifying class or using extra. Maybe I missed something, but if not then this would kinda answer my question

You did miss something @Arshalok, because all you need to do is call logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger) and from than on getLogger will return instances of your custom class

True @blues, the only issue is that you need to setLoggerClass before any getLogger, and then you need to cast getLogger return to your CustomLogger. But this can be achieved with a separate function with this logic.

@Arshalok if all you want is just add some custom params, why not use a logging adapter instead of a custom class?

@blues, because I need to trigger  custom actions on demand when logging. For example logging to database only when setting to true a custom param in info method. As far as I am aware the adapter would not give me this functionality.

@Arshalok what you describe should be handled by a filter. Add the database handler to your default logger, but give it a filter that blocks all logs that don't fit the criteria.

@blues, I know and this is done. But you still need to provide the trigger. I wanted to do this with custom parameter for each logging method, but ended up with function returning dictionary to extra parameter, since it's a much simpler solution. Even though not as elegant for the user as using custom parameters.
